# Convert MySQL date with milliseconds to Google Sheets' date format

Tags: google-sheets, date-formatting

I have the following string in Google Sheets, extracted from a MySQL date format:
`2018-05-28 23:10:23.477`

I need it to be converted to a date format in Google Sheets, including the milliseconds.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try:

```
=text(A1,"yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss.000")-0
```